# C# DataGridView how to illuminate current List<Action>

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to highlight the method that is being implemented  on datagridview right now.

This is List :

```
  public List<Action> functions = new List<Action>();
```

And inside i have a methods.  by adding for example.

```
functions.Add(waypoint1);
```

My datagridview after add method look like :

[image]

And i just want hightlight current waypoint.

to start list I use:

```
foreach (Action func in functions)
{
    func();
}
```

For example when `func()` number 2 is currenly  activated just highlight 2nd row.
When `func()` number 3 is currenly  activated just highlight 3rd row. I searched forum but don't find solution.Please be patient for newbie. Thank you.

**EDIT 1 :**
Added code of foreach loop in backgroundworker as you want.

```
private void DoWork_backgroundworker(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        foreach (Action func in functions)
        {
            func();
        }
    }
}
```

And button to start :

```
private void metroButton7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoWork_backgroundworker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: how do you imagine the highlighting to be? shall it have a different backcolour? the normal highlighting refers to the `SelectedRow`.

Comment: anything just want to know  which List is currenly doing .  Could be just normal like SelectedRow

Comment: are you running the foreach loop on the main thread?

Comment: in the backgroundworker by clicking button

Comment: could you please post the code

Comment: Added as you wish by edit

Comment: In my opinion every fucn() has own number [0] ,[1], [2]... And maybe is it to possible just when fucn() number = [0] , just selectrow [0] in datagridview?

Comment: is the order the same in your list and datagridview?

Comment: Its the same   ID on my datagridview = func [0] , ID =1 ,  = func[1]

Comment: does my answer work for you?

Comment: You really shouldn't [repost questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43080212/c-sharp-datagridview-how-to-illuminate-current-listaction#43080212), esp. not after such a short time!! - As it is done now, at least delete the 1st one!! - Also: Please make clearer what you mean 'implemented' as in coded or 'activated' as in running..

Comment: Mong Zhu Yes thank you it works! Btw you know how can i do the same but get and different backcolour? I just prefer a another color

Comment: @user7762338 I wrote an edit showing how to change the colour. Have a look and a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is ok for you that you use the `Selected` property for the highlighting you can use a normal for-loop (which will give you an indexer) and index the rows that belong to the items. Set simply the `Selected` property of that `Row` to `true`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < functions.Count; i++)
{
    //select the row before action is started
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;

    // execute your action 
    functions[i]();

    //unselect the row when job is finished
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = false;

}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to change the selection/highlight colour use the `dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor` property. Put this line before the for-loop:

```
dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
```